# Is it possible to modify a rounded rectangle's radius in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As the title implies, I have drawn a rounded rectangle with a larger radius in Photoshop.  Now I want to reduce its radius. Is this possible without deleting it?

Comment: If you have access to Fireworks, consider giving that a spin. So much handier for mixing vector and raster work than PhotoShop.

Comment: vote to close: I think that Jichao you need a good book of photoshop and study the software more. This is not real a question, if you know that you can deleted, and add the right ratio why do not you do it? It doesn't cost you more than 10 sec.

Comment: @Littlemad: This is a perfectly reasonable question. Just because you can delete it and start over doesn't mean you shouldn't search for a quicker way of doing it.

Comment: @Calvin Huang: I agree on what you are saying, I am pointing out that what we are talking about is not an effect that you need many steps that takes you several minutes, it is one setting to change in the toolbar. We are talking about few seconds fix that he already knows how to do it. Because of this it feels a bit like laziness. I understand that Jichao is learning photoshop because I saw another basic question about slicing and I feel that he needs to study a bit more a book of photoshop or spending a bit more time with it. So it would help him much more in that way.

Comment: @little mad, what if you have 20 such rectangles, what if each ones location was exact. This is definitely a valid question, and i would be very interested in knowing a better solution

Comment: That already would be different for me, it is a bigger problem. I am ok if you guys think that it is relevant. I do not want to argue. To me there is no much overthinking, sometimes doing the monkey job it is quicker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no convenient way of changing corner radius in Photoshop after you've begun drawing a shape. This is one area where Fireworks is pretty nice, as you can simply click on the diamonds at each corner to change the radius.

However, one work around is to use an outer stroke. If the stroke is the same color as the shape, then it will create the illusion of rounded corners. The stroke thickness will be the corner radius, and you can change that at any time.

It's probably also possible to use Photoshop scripting to transform and convert the corners of a vector shape (as opposed to a rasterized shape). But that requires you to have some JavaScript knowledge and to figure out the formula for transforming the corner anchors. But if you were so inclined, you could probably create an action that let you select a shape, type in a new corner radius, and automatically do the transformations for you.

Comment: Comprehensive answer, possibly could be improved by differentiating vector shape layers from other ways of drawing shapes in PS.

Comment: Nice tip on the outer stroke.  I like it because you can continue to tweak the size and aspect ratio of the shape and the corners stay the same. Looks like CC lets you reset the corner size, but that's still annoying if you have to manually do it each time... also I'm still on CS6, so no corner radius in the properties window.

Comment: this is one of the reasons why the dev team of this software should be fired instantly.. its 2018 and e still have to deal with this trash

Answer (score 36):

http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/modify-shapes.html
You can find the answer in above link.

I assume that the shape is already created. Select the shape layer and click the shape using Path selection tool (<kbd>A</kbd>). Then go to `Window > Properties`. Now there you can find all four corner radius values. Simply click and edit the radius values.

[image]

Comment: Hi San, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Hi Vincent, I accept your terms. In that Video  Mr Rafael clearly explained who to edit rounded corners in photoshop cc.

Comment: Hehe, they are not my 'terms', just something to ensure that your answer stays of value in case the link goes down. So, could you please tell us, however short, *how* mr Rafael manages to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I assume that the shape is already created. Select the shape layer and click the shape using Path selection tool(A). Then go to Window > Properties. Now there you can find all four corner radius value. Simply click and edit the radius value.

Comment: Adobe hides stuff so well.

Comment: How can I get this menu? I have only `&Masks` while click on rounded rectangle, not `live shape properties`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can all you need to do is install

http://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/corner-editor-photoshop-script/

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to GD. This is an interesting script. Well spotted!

Comment: You need to type in the number then click the corner button to make the change. Ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it seems like there is still interest in a good answer. Here is the short version: Use smart objects. Make the rectangle as a symbol in Illustrator.

In a bit more detail, here is how you do it:

1. Open a new document in illustrator. Set the unit to pixels and the colorspace to RGB. If you do this a lot, save the document template.
2. Use the rounded rectangle tool in illustrator to draw out the shape. Remember that while you have the mouse button down, you can use the up and down arrow keys to change the rounding. Chances are that you shape will not be an exact pixel, so once it looks about right, you should delete it and click on the canvas. That will drop a new shape like the one you just drew. Adjust the pixels to exact values (but keep the rounding the way you set it).
3. Open the symbols palette (from the window menu if you need to) and press the new symbol button. Name it and check the box for "enable guides for 9 slice scaling".

Now the rectangle is ready to use in photoshop.

1. Select the version on the artboard. Copy it.
2. Paste it into your photoshop document. A dialog will come up for how to import it. Choose smart object (the top option in CS5).
3. If you want multiple copies, just alt-drag it or dupe the layer. To edit it, just click the layer icon and it will open in illustrator. Since it is a symbol, you can just change the size however you like and save the document. The new size will be reflected in photoshop with the same rounded corners.
4. I suggest you don't apply any size transforms in photoshop so that things stay clear. That way, if it is 240px x 80px in illustrator, it is the same in photoshop.
5. If you need multiple sizes, then make a layer style in photoshop, but work from multiple illustrator originals.

Comment: Welcome to GD.  That's a very well thought-out and explained answer.  It doesn't really answer the question's (slightly impossible) request to do it without deleting the original object, but nevertheless is a good guide for how to do it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to delete it, or trying to work on the mask that is generating to create the radious (but is quicker to delete and restart than not touching the mask).

Answer (score 0):

## How to add or modify round corners to a square or rectangle already created in Photoshop

If you already have your rectangle and want to add some round corners, you can do it this way:

**If you need to decrease the radius (corner less rounded),** the easiest is to use the guides to trace a new rectangle with the
"Rectangle Selection Tool", do the steps below and use these new
smaller corner radius as a layer mask on your larger corner radius
rectangle... and fill the shape.

**If your rectangle had a texture**, you might need to use the "Clone Stamp Tool" and fill these new corners. That's where using a layer mask is useful.

**If you have many round corner rectangles to adjust**, you can simply duplicate the layer mask you just created and apply it to your other rectangles. Layer mask can be resized as well.

Unless you previously used a layer mask on your round corner rectangle, you can't "invent" pixels; you'll need to add them back somehow.

---

## How to create a round corner rectangle or square in Photoshop

To correct a round corner rectangles or squares directly in Adobe Photoshop, you can create a new round corner rectangle, and use it on a layer mask to help you fill the corner to be smaller.

**1) Select the "Rectangle Marquee Tool" and trace a rectangle the size you need on a new layer**

**2) Go in the menu "Select", then "Modify", then "Smooth"**

**3) Enter the value of the corner radius you want for your rectangle or square.**

**4) Add this new rectangle to a layer mask on the layer where the original rectangle is**, and use the "Clone Stamp Tool" to fill the new corners or simply fill it with a solid color.

---

## How to use a round corner rectangle or square from Adobe Illustrator and import it in Photoshop to modify an existing shape

Another way is to simply create it in Adobe Illustrator, and copy/paste the shape on a layer in Photoshop... and use it as layer mask. You will still need to fill the missing parts of the corner as mentioned above.

**1) Press on the "Rectangle Tool" until you see a menu offering you other shapes. Select the "Rounded Rectangle Tool."**

[image: How to create a vector rounded rectangle in Adobe Illustrator]

**2) Click once on your canvas (don't trace the rectangle) and some options will appear.**

You can enter your corner radius there and the size of your shape if you want.

[image: How to add precise corner radius for round corner in Illustrator]

**If you don't know what size you want**, you can still select your corner radius, create that shape and then delete it. THEN trace your rectangle as you want; that's a quick way to set the corner radius of the next rectangles you'll trace!

**If you don't really care about a precise measure for the corner radius or simply don't know what value to use**, you can simply trace your rectangle or square, and click on the little dot in the corners; drag them to adjust the corner to the shape you want.

You can also import your Photoshop rectangle image if you want to adjust your new round corner visually and prefer Illustrator to do it. The Photoshop image will only serve as a guide.

[image: Adjust round corner visually]

**3) Once you're done, you can simply copy and paste that new round corner rectangle in your Photoshop file, on a layer mask applied to your previous shape. Then you'll need to fill that shape with the "Clone Stamp Tool" or a solid color to fill back these new corners.**